# Python - Unable to use plot_trisurf to plot a 2D array in Matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a 2D array which I am trying to plot using `plot_trisurf` and I can't seem to make it work no matter what I try.

Here follows a minimally reproducible example where I am able to use `plot_surface`

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import cm
import numpy as np

frames = []
for _ in range(5):
    matrix = np.array([
            [np.random.normal(20, 3) for _ in range(6)] 
            for _ in range(6)
        ], 
        dtype = np.float32
    )   
    frames.append(matrix)

fig= plt.figure(figsize = [6, 5], dpi = 100) 
        
ax = fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1, projection='3d')
ax.set_zlim(10, 30)

data = frames[0]    
X, Y = np.meshgrid(
    range(len(frames[0])),
    range(len(frames[0][0]))
)  
ax.plot_surface(X, Y, data, cmap=cm.Spectral, linewidth=1)
plt.show()
```

yielding

[image]

But when I try

```
ax.plot_trisurf(X, Y, data, cmap=cm.Spectral, linewidth=1)
```

I get an error that `X` and `Y` must be equal-length 1D arrays, so then I tried

```
ax.plot_trisurf(X.flatten(), Y.flatten(), data, cmap=cm.Spectral, linewidth=1)
```

But then I get the stacktrace

```
Command failed: python3 main.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 25, in 
    ax.plot_trisurf(X.flatten(), Y.flatten(), data, cmap=cm.Spectral, linewidth=1)
  File "/usr/local/lib64/python3.8/site-packages/mpl_toolkits/mplot3d/axes3d.py", line 2051, in plot_trisurf
    zt = z[triangles]
IndexError: index 6 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 6
```

---

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong? I have tried many things and looked at the documentation, but can't seem to understand what I am missing.

Comment: `data.flatten()`

Comment: If you know your data on a regular grid, don't use `trisurf`

Comment: Off topic, but the data generation you use (good thing, btw. It should be a given, but it is rare enough to see question with this example data generation to happily note it when we see one), could be shortened that way: `frames=np.random.normal(20, 3, (5,6,6))`. `np.random.normal` accept an optional 3rd parameter which is the shape of the random data to generate. In this case it would generate 180 random number, in the wanted shape.

Comment: @gboffi Oh right, I'm silly, thank you. You should write it as a standalone answer so I can accept it.

Comment: I'm happy I had been helpful. Thank you.